# converting iso time string returns wrong date time object in php

Tags: php, datetime, iso

Converting iso string in zulu time returns the next time. I'm not sure what I've done wrong please. see example below

```
$dateTime = "2020-04-31T23:59:58Z"
(new DateTime($dateTime)); // returns  2020-05-01 23:59:58.0 +00:00
```

Answer (score 4):

April has 30 days.

As such, `DateTime` returns "April 31st" as May 1st (April 30th + 1 day).

Comment: Thank you! figured that out  15 minutes of posting this